# App has crashed (stopped)

Tags: java, android

I just started with Android and Java development and got this on my AVD simulator. Also I found many same questions here but to be honest I don't really know how to fix it. My app hase just 3 buttons nothing more. Also they are not active.. I just put them in `Graphical Layout`. This is Logcat:

```
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042): Process: com.example.reserved, PID: 2042
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:Resource ID #0x7f070000
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:107)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at com.example.reserved.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:21)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-21 05:05:13.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is line 22 in `MainActivity` where is the error

```
package com.example.reserved;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here are the buttons from the `Activity_main`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:text="@string/Rest" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/Rest1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/Rest2" />
```

This is `main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.reserved.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Updated - `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.reserved"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post *onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:21)*

Comment: Your posted code is not related to your logcat....so post the MainActivity all code...

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question and posted full `MainActivity`.

Comment: What is on the r.menu.main file? Can you post it?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question again

Comment: `menu.main` is available in your `project-->res-->menu-->main.xml` ...post this file...

Comment: try clean and build , then clear lint marks &  make sure you define your main.xml by correctly way in your manifest.xml

Comment: @Manish I've updated the question with the main.xml

Comment: @minafawzy when I make clean I get error in `MainActivity.java` on `R...`. Error is `R cannot be resolved to a variable`. You can see where are `R's` in the question above. I didn't put them there..

Comment: then this problem in your xml , check your xml , and check if you add any files to your project Ex: images , to dont be with upper letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added all the strings mentioned above in the strings.xml.
Please try to run the example with only this much code in MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.reserved;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

And your activity_main.xml to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:text="Rest" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Rest1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Rest2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you able to see the 3 buttons in your output, if so please accept the answer

Comment: please check my updated answer and run your project and let me know

Comment: Still crashing. I don't know what to do.. It's just 3 buttons .. nothing more.

Comment: please post your manifest.xml, is the error still the same or its different, try cleaning your project and launch the app

Comment: Hey i tried the above code in my IDE[eclipse] it's working perfectly. Here'e how i started out, NEW ANDROID APPLICATION PROJECT and then give required name and package name  and select compile with 19[in your case] and min required to also 19. in the create activity screen you have to select "create a blank activity" and then move the code and try. If this fails then there is something wrong with your avd

Comment: I have another folder/project loaded automatically when I start this project and there I have error. The error is `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.` in `res-values-v21->style_base.xml`

Comment: Is it possible this to cause all the problems? on the lines where is the error is -> `<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
           parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">
    </style>`

Comment: I will try to start new project like you said. Just a momment and I will let you know.

Comment: Just for testing purpose can you move the other project from the work space and try

Comment: You mean to remove it from there and to leave only current project?

Comment: Yes if the other project is not important then move it as there is no syntax error in code as this is the last option. Were you getting the same error even after creating a new project. If you have not tried it please do that first and then try moving

Comment: Ok, I started new project and copy/paste the source you provide and is working fine. Please can you tell me what exactly was the problem? I see that you removed `+` in `android:layout_below="@id/...` And some code from `MainActivity.java`

Comment: yes i removed them because + creates a additional entry inside R.java as there is already a hex code generated for your button its not requuired. Happy coding enjoy

Comment: Thank's again for your help!